# iBeacon background ranging

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-location, ibeacon, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to set my application as a way to just start ranging in the background and get a notification when the user hit the shoulder button or home button(not all the time) and I don't want using background mode.

So I coded this in swift, it works when my app is working in background just for 10 seconds and ranging won't be restarted when the user re-enter or exit from region but I get callback for about 180 seconds which means my ranging will work for 3 minutes but it only send notification in its first 10 seconds.

I started a task in the background and then call my run function which will wake up init function. I'll be happy if someone shares its experience.

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    BackgroundTask1.run(application:
    application) { (BackgroundTask1_) in


    }
```

run and init functions:

```
class func run(application: UIApplication, handler: (BackgroundTask1) -> ()) {

    let backgroundTask = BackgroundTask1(application: application)
    backgroundTask.begin()
    handler(backgroundTask)
}

func init_()
{
    let uuidString = "43F2ACD1-5522-4E0D-9E3F-4A828EA12C24"
    let beaconRegionIdentifier = "Hello"
    let beaconUUID:UUID = UUID(uuidString:uuidString)!
    beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: beaconUUID, identifier: beaconRegionIdentifier)

    beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = true

    locationManager_ = CLLocationManager()


    if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse) {
        locationManager_!.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    locationManager_?.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    locationManager_!.delegate = self
    locationManager_!.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically=false

    locationManager_?.startRangingBeacons(in: beaconRegion)
}
```

This is notificaion's code:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {

    print("sdljflkj")

    if beacons.count == 0 {

        return
    }


    let currentbeacon = beacons[0]
    lastproximity = currentbeacon.proximity

    if currentbeacon.proximity == CLProximity.immediate{


        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {

            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            content.title = "Forget Me Not"
            content.body = "Are you forgetting something?"
            content.sound = .default()

            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "ForgetMeNot", content: content, trigger: nil)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)

            print("here1")

            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "iBeaconFoundReceivedNotification"), object: nil, userInfo: ["Major":currentbeacon.major, "minor": currentbeacon.minor])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can only run a background task for 180 seconds on iOS before your app will be killed.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Paulw11, yes but it does just work for 10 seconds and after that I can't see that call back is working by printing it in my swift console, but it doesn't work after 10 seconds on the phone, it won't send me the notification.

Comment: @davidgyoung, I wrote an application to work on the background for 180 seconds after like the one you did, but it just works for 10 seconds and the ranging call back for 180  seconds but it doesn't send any notification after 10 seconds, I tested your application and I got the same result as mine.

Comment: I am surprised to hear that sending a local notification after the first 10 seconds does not work.  Perhaps there is a problem with the notification sending code.  Can you show it?

Comment: @davidgyoung I already added above. I'll be happy if you look into it.